# USB порт на UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, usb, port

уважаемые гуру. У меня установлен ubuntu22, когда я вставляю флешку в usb порт, то почему-то он флешку не видит, но флешка светится, а если вставить в другой порт, то все видит, но не копирует файлы из флешки, пишет "ошибка копирования....ошибка ввода/выводы". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это исправить?

Comment: Для начала вставить в другой компьютер и посмотреть на результат

Comment: сначала убедитесь что проблема не с самой флешкой, попробуйте вставить в комп другую флешку если есть, ну или как написали выше вставьте эту флешку но в другой комп и посмотрите что будет. Тут либо флешка на издыхании либо usb-порты в компе раздолбанные.

Comment: я же написал, что флешку не видит только на одном порту, на других видит, но с копированием какие-то проблемы

Comment: У Ubuntu нет версии 22. Есть 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish (LTS) и 22.10 Kinetic Kudu

Comment: Всё верно, версия 22.04, я просто полагал, что это и так будет понятно